# Cesium An error occurred while rendering. Rendering has stopped

Tags: runtime-error, cesiumjs, vertex

Today, I'm asking for help from the community because I have a problem with Cesium. When I run a command to display a path I get this error. Whether it's Firefox, Chrome or even Edge, I get the same error.
Firefox 88.0.1 (64 bits)

```
An error occurred while rendering.  Rendering has stopped.
RuntimeError: Vertex texture fetch support is required to render polylines. The maximum number of vertex texture image units must be greater than zero.
RuntimeError@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:235274:11
./node_modules/cesium/Source/Scene/PolylineCollection.js/PolylineCollection.prototype.update@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:393795:13
```

```
Error loading image for billboard: DeveloperError: Width must be less than or equal to the maximum texture size (0).  Check maximumTextureSize.
DeveloperError@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:179691:11
Texture@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:304841:11
resizeAtlas@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:423958:29
addImage@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:424063:16
./node_modules/cesium/Source/Scene/TextureAtlas.js/TextureAtlas.prototype.addImage/indexPromise<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:424120:13
fulfilled/p<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:476336:34
_then/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:476437:13
processQueue@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:476787:11
_resolve@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:476473:16
promiseResolve@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:476499:11
```

[webgl1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aakll.png)

Comment: Hi, typically this site asks people to copy/paste the text of the message, not just post a screenshot, as the text is searchable.  That said, the top line in each error hints at a broken WebGL implementation that isn't reporting any available texture resources.  What graphics card is this?  What does [WebGL Report](https://webglreport.com/) say?

Comment: Yes, it's better by text... On the WebGL page, it says that my browser supports webgl 1 & 2.

Comment: Your error messages talk about particular parts of WebGL listed in the report.  For example "Vertex texture fetch support is required to render polylines. The maximum number of vertex texture image units must be greater than zero."  And also: "Width must be less than or equal to the maximum texture size (0).  Check maximumTextureSize."  The WebGL Report should list the available image units and max size, and if they're zeros, your environment isn't providing a usable WebGL context to render in.

Comment: Cesium currently uses WebGL 1 by the way, so you can ignore the WebGL 2 page for now.

Comment: I added a capture picture of my windows screen on Webgl params of my firefox.

Comment: Adding ImageryLayer (UrlTemplateImageryLayer in my case) was causing this issue for me. Removing that solved it.

Answer (score 1):

This was happening for my team while using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in a VirtualBox VM.
The error occurred in Google Chrome browser on, for example, this page:
https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=3D%20Tiles%20Clipping%20Planes.html

In our case, this resolved the issue:

1. Shut down your VM.
2. Open the Virtualbox settings for the VM
3. Un-check the box Display -> Enable 3D Acceleration
4. Once that setting is *OFF* then it should work for you as a CPU-only renderer.
5. Then, of course, start the machine back up.

It's slower using CPU-only graphics, but it helped us with this testing issue.